# binary partition an array using java

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner(first year uni student) programmer trying to solve this problem which i'm finding somewhat difficult. If you are to answer this question, don't provide me with a complex daunting algorithm that will leave me scratching my head. I'll really appreciate it if you explain it step my step (both logically/conceptually then through code)

The problem is as follows:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwq4K.png)

I have tried to attempt it and my code only works for a certain case that i tested.

```
package com.company;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Main {

public static int[][] binary_partition(int array[], int k){
    int x = (int) Math.pow(2,k);
    int[][] partition = new int[((array.length/x)*2)][array.length/x];
    int divisor = array.length/x;

    if ((array.length % 2) != 0){
        return partition;
    }
    if (divisor >= array.length-1){
        return partition;
    }
    if (k==1){
        return partition;
    }

    int p = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<((array.length/x)*2);i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<array.length/x;j++)
        {
            partition[i][j] = array[p];
            p += 1;
        }
    }
    return partition;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] array = {3, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3};
    int[][] result = binary_partition(array,2);

    for (int[] x : result){
        for (int y : x)
        {
            System.out.print(y + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't very well-defined in the specification; the language makes it unclear whether a partition has k elements or whether it should be divisible into 2^k sets with the same number of elements. The best I can tell is that you are supposed to divide the partition the array into 2^k distinct sets, since the partition in example does not satisfy the property that each set is divisible into 2^2 subsets.

Comment: Please add all relevant information directly to your question. it makes it easier for others to read and answer and also prevents link-rot.

Comment: sorry about that, but the snapshot I shared was the only thing provided in my uni tutorial worksheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but this solution creates a function that partitions an array with the right length into 2^k sets. 
First, an interesting fact: using the bitshift operator `<<` on an integer increases its value by a power of two. So to find out the size of your partition, you could write

```java
int numPartitions = 1 << k; // Equivalent to getting the integer value of 2^k
```

With this fact, the function becomes

```java
public static int[][] partition(int[] set, int k) {
    if (set == null)
        return null; // Don't try to partition a null reference

    // If k = 0, the partition of the set is just the set
    if (k == 0) {
        int[][] partition = new int[1][set.length];
        // Copy the original set into the partition
        System.arraycopy(set, 0, partition[0], 0, set.length);
        return partition;
    }

    int numPartitions = 1 << k; // The number of sets to partition the array into
    int numElements = set.length / numPartitions; // The number of elements per partition

    /* Check if the set has enough elements to create a partition and make sure
       that the partitions are even */
    if (numElements == 0 || set.length % numElements != 0)
        return null; // Replace with an error/exception of your choice

    int[][] partition = new int[numPartitions][numElements];
    int index = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < numPartitions; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < numElements; c++) {
            partition[r][c] = set[index++]; // Assign an element to the partition
        }
    }

    return partition;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nolan, clears everything up :). One more question regarding how you initialized the partition array, do we need to specify the size of the partition 2d array or does it automatically allocate itself when you run the main loop underneath?

Comment: I was rereading and I realized that I forget to add the correct parameters to the `new int[][]` so I just fixed it. To answer your question, you do need to specify the parameters. I'm not sure if you're supposed to be checking for edge cases or errors but I've included several `if` statements that do that just in case

Answer (score 0):

There are a few lines of your code where the intention is not clear. For example, it is not clear why you are validating `divisor >= array.length-1`. Checking `k==1` is also incorrect because k=1 is a valid input to the method. In fact, all your validation checks are not needed. All you need to validate is that `array.length` is divisible by `x`.

The main problem that you have seems to be that you mixed up the lengths of the resulting array.

The resulting array should have a length of `array.length / x`, and each of the subarrays should have a length of `x`, hence:

```
int[][] partition = new int[array.length/x][x];
```

If you also fix your bounds on the for loops, your code should work.

Your nested for loop can be rewritten as a single for loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
{
    int index = i / x;
    int subArrayIndex = i % x;
    partition[index][subArrayIndex] = array[i];
}
```

You just need to figure out which indices a an element `array[i]` belongs by dividing and getting the remainder.